# OSError: [WinError 126] Shapely

Tags: python, import, pycharm, polygon, shapely

I am trying to import the `Polygon` function from `shapely.geometry.polygon` in pycharm, but I keep getting an error. I've tried conda-forge installing, pip installing, I've looked through a number of forums. I can't seem to get the package to read.

Any advice?

[image]

Comment: Yes that does work. I ended up just needing to switch my interpreter to the correct env where I already saved the PyPi file too.

Answer (score 1):

The Shapely module is not correctly installed in your virtualenv.

Take a look at the available distributions in [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/#files)

You need to check that a Wheel (*.whl) package is available for your Python version + Windows version.

For instance, if you use Python 3.9 on Windows 64bits, you can install Shapely-1.7.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.

You can try installing with `pip`:

```sh
pip install shapely
```